# Bootstrap 3 - toggle button not displaying on Android Devices

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an a off-canvas nav working. It works well on my machine with desktop browsers. It also works with iOS devices. However, the toggle button disappears when testing most Android devices.

Here is the page: http://cahoots-clients.com/cahoots-html3/offcanvas-working.html

Here are the test results: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/eda1d0e540f787186a64341ccb57d191c5bad09f

I'm using 3.2.0 bootstrap.css out of the box.

Comment: Works on my real Android device.

Comment: Works fine on two devices: Galaxy note 8.0 + Galaxy note 2

Comment: Yeah, it works on some but not all for some reason. If you check out my test results link above you can see what I mean. For example, Samsung Galaxy S2 doesn't work among many others. @DavidG what device did you preview the site in?

Comment: Mine is an HTC One (but running CyanogenMod). Have you seen it not working on a real device or just in BrowserStack?

Comment: I only have 3 devices at my disposal and but they also look good in BrowserStack.

Comment: Emulator in Chrome seems fine too

Comment: Probably a bug in some versions of the crappy stock Android Browser app?

Comment: @cvrebert - Yeah, could be. As all of you know it's super hard to test out all devices. Just want to make sure that I can get as many to look good as I can. As a friend of mine pointed out BrowserStack in an emulator so it may not be accurate all of the time. Question for anybody: what system do you use to test for mobile?